# Input fields lose css attributes after text input

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table of cells in html

```
<table id="grid">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="3" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="6" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="7" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="8" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="9" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="10" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="11" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="12" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="13" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="14" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="15" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="16" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="17" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="18" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="19" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="20" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="21" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="22" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="23" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="24" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="25" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="26" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="27" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="28" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="29" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="30" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="31" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="32" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="33" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="34" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="35" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="36" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="37" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="38" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="39" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="40" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="41" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="42" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="43" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="44" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="45" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="46" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="47" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="48" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="49" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="50" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="51" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="52" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="53" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="54" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="55" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="56" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="57" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="58" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="59" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="60" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="61" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="62" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="63" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="64" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="65" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="66" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="67" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="68" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="69" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="70" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="71" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="72" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="73" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="74" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="75" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="76" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="77" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="78" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="79" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="80" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="81" /></td>
        
      </tr>

      

      
    
  </table>
```

With the following css

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
table { margin: 10px; }
tr:first-child td {
    border-top-color: black;
}
tr:nth-child(3n) td {
    border-bottom-color: black;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
td:first-child {
    border-left-color: black;
}
td:nth-child(3n) {
    border-right-color: black;
}
input {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

input:hover {
    background: #eee;
}
```

This allows each cell to be editable and when you hover over the cell it changes colour slightly

I added this js to add values to the cells

```
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((cell) => {
     cell.textContent = "1";



})
```

This does its job it fills the grid with the number but it also makes the css stop working it no longer lets me edit and no longer has the hover effects it also seems to change the font?

Im i correct in using 'textContent' ?

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: If you want tochange element text, use `innerText`

Comment: @pavel Seems to produce the same result im afraid

Comment: I didn't see you have there inputs. `cell.innerText += "1";` Or set value to directly input (using `querySelector` and `.value`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the value to the input, not to the cell as a text,
ex, like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((cell) => {
    cell.querySelector('input').value = '1'
})
```

also, it's not stopping CSS, and it's important to know that your cells are editable because you have input elements, it's not doable to make elements editable by CSS,